# Sorting alpha-numeric array?

Tags: ruby

I would like to sort an alphanumeric array in Ruby and return a sorted array back.

For example:

```
["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple"]
```

to return:

```
["apple", "jim", 1, 4, "world"]
```

so that where there is an object of the same class in the same position before the sort, just now it's numerical/alphabetical.

Comment: It seems to me that *performing* this kind of sort is not the problem here. *Needing* one is. I don't know your specific use case but you're trying to treat a single array as two separate collections and it smells pretty bad IMHO.

Comment: I don't care why the asker wants to do this.  It's an interesting question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's why I'm not downvoting or flagging it. I'm just trying to help the OP by providing my view. It's cool to solve tricky problems in clever ways but I believe that storing objects in arrays should not be tricky in the first place.

Comment: @Tom, I can't disagree, and have resolved to be less self-indulgent in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

```
xs            = ["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple", 5, 6]
sorted_by_cls = xs.group_by(&:class).each { |k,vs| vs.sort!.reverse! }
sorted_xs     = xs.map(&:class).map { |c| sorted_by_cls[c].pop }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a universal solution to the problem if it's possible for the initial array to contain more groups of `Fixnum` than just one. For `["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple", 5, 6]` it yields `["apple", "jim", 6, 5, "world", 1, 4]`

Comment: @Tom Fixed -- forgot the bangs on `sort` and `reverse`.

Comment: @user3138038 It's `group_by`, not `grouped_by`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how this compares to other solutions, but here's another one:

```
xs = ["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple", 5, 6]
classes = xs.map(&:class)
sorts = Hash[*classes.uniq.map {|c| [c, xs.select {|x| x.class == c}.sort]}.flatten(1)]
classes.map {|c| sorts[c].shift} # => ["apple", "jim", 1, 4, "world", 5, 6]
```

Comment: Very nice, Peter.  (Forgot to +1 earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple"]

arr.each_with_index.group_by {|e| e.first.class}.values.map {|g|\
g.map(&:first).sort.zip(g.map(&:last).sort)}\
.each_with_object(Array.new(arr.size)) {|e,a| e.each {|f,i| a[i] = f}}
  # => ["apple", "jim", 1, 4, "world"]
```

Let's go through this:

- `a1 = arr.each.with_index.group_by {|e| e.first.class} # => {String=>[["world", 0], ["jim", 1], ["apple", 4]], Fixnum=>[[4, 2], [1, 3]]}`
- `a21, a22 = a1.values #=>[[["world",0],["jim",1],["apple",4]],[[4,2],[1,3]]]`
- `a31 = a21.map(&:first) # => ["world", "jim", "apple"]`
- `a41 = a31.sort # => ["apple", "jim", "world"]`
- `a51 = a21.map(&:last).sort # => [0, 1, 4]`
- `a61 = a41.zip(a51) # => [["apple", 0], ["jim", 1], ["world", 4]]`
- `a62 = a22.map(&:first).sort.zip(a22.map(&:last).sort) # => [[1,2], [4,3]]`
- `[a61, a62].each_with_object(Array.new(5)) {|e,a| e.each {|f,i| a[i] = f}}`

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting problem. Here's how I approached it assuming an alphanumeric array. Partition the array into alpha and numeric subarrays, sort them, and reconstitute based on the position and class of the object in the original array.

```
arr = ["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple"]
alpha_num = arr.partition { |l| l.is_a? String }.map(&:sort)
arr.map { |l| l.is_a?(String) ? alpha_num.first.shift : alpha_num.last.shift }
```

My generalized solution is not much different than that of FMc:

```
arr = ["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple", 5, 6]
sorted_hash = arr.group_by(&:class).each_value(&:sort!)
arr.map { |l| sorted_hash[l.class].shift }
```

Comment: Very nice.  Consider generalizing to arbitrary classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["world", "jim", 4, 1, "apple", "cabbage"]

is = a.each_index.group_by{|i| a[i].class}.values
.flat_map{|is| [is, is.sort_by{|i| a[i]}].transpose}
.sort.map(&:last)
a.values_at(*is)
```